# Why do delegates in a none static class work like they are static C#

Tags: c#

Hi I've modified some delegate tutorial code to experiment and I know there are prebuilt delegates available but without taking those into account.

I don't understand how the following works which I will break down:

```
 class Program
{
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Human human1 = new Human(20);

        BuffsProccessor buffsProccessor1 = new BuffsProccessor();
        BuffsProccessor buffsProccessor2 = new BuffsProccessor();
        BuffsCanAdd buffsCanAdd = new BuffsCanAdd();
        BuffsProccessor.BuffHandler buffHandler = buffsCanAdd.AddStrengthBoost;
        buffHandler += buffsCanAdd.AddIntelligenceBoost;
        buffsProccessor1.ProcessBuffs(human1, buffHandler);
        buffsProccessor2.ProcessBuffs(human1, buffHandler);
    }
}

public class BuffsProccessor
{
    public delegate void BuffHandler(Race race);

    public void ProcessBuffs(Race race, BuffHandler buffHandler)
    {
        buffHandler(race);
        race.ShowStats();
    }
}

public class BuffsCanAdd
{
    public void AddStrengthBoost(Race race)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Adding strength boost");
    }

    public void AddIntelligenceBoost(Race race)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Adding intelligence boost");
    }
}
```

What I'm finding confusing is how come this line works like the class and delegate are static:

```
            BuffsProccessor.BuffHandler buffHandler = buffsCanAdd.AddStrengthBoost;
```

the class and the delegate within the class are accessible without an instance of the BuffsProccessor class.

What is happening in memory when

```
BuffsProccessor.BuffHandler buffHandler = buffsCanAdd.AddStrengthBoost;
```

the buffHandler is there I'm finding this so confusing I'm struggling to form my question. Since the new keyword isn't being used how and where is it being stored in memory if it isn't in an instance of the BuffProccessorClass?

I hope this makes sense I can't find any delegate tutorials that answers this specific question.

Comment: Think of a delegate as a special type of class.  So the delegate defined in the class is not part of the instance of the class but a sub definition you can access via the class.

Comment: It is a feature (aka restriction) in the C# language, the compiler infers `this` for the delegate target object.  A counter-example is the C++/CLI language, you must always provide the target object in the construction call.  It even supports ["unbound delegates"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-define-and-use-delegates-cpp-cli?view=msvc-170#to-use-unbound-delegates), allowing specifying the target object when invoking the delegate.  It does not get a lot of use.

Comment: @juharr thanks for your responses, its starting to make more sense now, so basically the delegate is like a class that is being accessed via the BuffProccessor class.

The delegate is then being assigned as its own instance as buffhandler which is then being stored in memory from the answer below with the new keyword being hidden.

Then its the instance of the delegate that is being used.

The only thing I'm slightly confused with now is how the delegate is accessible when the class itself is not static and how its the delegate not the class it came from that is instantiated.

Answer (score 3):

What, do you mean, "without an instance of the `BuffsProccessor` class"? It's right there:

```
buffsCanAdd.AddStrengthBoost;
```

See that `buffsCanAdd`? That's your instance. If it were a static method you could just say `AddStrengthBoost` without the object before it.

The reason it works is that delegates don't just keep a reference to a method, they can also store a reference to the object to invoke the method on. This is mandatory for delegates to non instance methods, because you can't just invoke those methods on thin air.

As for your second question, there *is* a `new` involved, it's just that since C# 2, you can skip it and the compiler will put it for you. Before that, you *had* to do it by hand:

```
BuffsProccessor.BuffHandler buffHandler = new BuffsProccessor.BuffHandler(buffsCanAdd.AddStrengthBoost);
```

But now it's considered bad style.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I understand now how its being stored in memory from your example.

Although the part when you mentioned the buffsCanAdd instance, is an instance of a different class which the delegate doesn't come from. I meant an instance of the BuffsProcessor class.

Comment: Well, a delegate is a type. It doesn't belong to a particular instance. It's like if you declared another class inside of `BuffsProccessor`, you can use it even without an instance of `BuffsProccessor`.

Comment: Ok thanks I will look into how classes inside of classes work this is something that I'm unfamiliar with.

Comment: Unlike in Java, where inner classes have some quirks you need to be aware of, in C#, they don't work any differently from classes outside of classes (besides access modifiers, but that doesn't change anything here).